# Dualboot Windows/Ubuntu - No sound on headphones USB (HyperX Cloud)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, headset, dualboot

I really tried to look everywhere to find a solution but there is nothing.

My problem is the next one : Today I decided to go on my Ubuntu (installed in dual boot), once I finished what I wanted to do there, I decided to come back on Windows 10 but I had no sound !

If I plug my headset with the jack or any other devices, the sound works, but I can't make it work with the USB plug and I need it ! The sound was working perfectly yesterday, and same today on Ubuntu.

I tried uninstalling sound drivers (realtek...), tried to find the HyperX Cloud drivers... but nothing worked. Some people said to put it in "sleep mode" or even "fully shutdown" but none worked.

I really don't know why that dual boot on Ubuntu made my USB headset not work anymore. If you could help it would be great !

Thank you guys

Comment: You probably should have started by simply replugging the USB receiver. And no, it's NOT related with the dual-boot. The device either failed (easy test, try it again in Ubuntu) or there's a problem with Windows.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the "replugging the USB receiver" part, I left it as it is, tried to plug it elsewhere, tried to not plug it.... It works fine in Ubuntu but no more in Windows (only with the USB connector). And before going on Ubuntu (via dual-boot) it was working fine, that's why I did conclude on this one. Ubuntu wanted to do some updates since I didn't use it for long, don't know if it's that neither

Comment: Are you really dual-booting or running Lubuntu as a virtual Machine?

Comment: Yeah I'm dual-booting. At the start of my PC I can choose to go on Windows or Ubuntu (Windows by default)

Comment: With a 'GNU GRUB' screen at start I mean

Comment: Ok, I don't know how I really did that, but it works again.
So I went to 'Device Manager' and there in 'Input and output audio' I saw a device which had 'SPDIF' in his name, I completely uninstalled it, refreshed the devices (with left click 'Search modifications...') and I also uninstalled another device which had 'libusbk' (i think ?) because it had inside it "hyperx virtual surround" driver